# Is it possible to replace win+x "Command prompt" with git bash?

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

I know there is an option to replace the Command Prompt with Powershell in the Windows+X menu, I'd really like to replace it with Git Bash.

I looked around the registry but nothing caught my eye there.

It would be fine by me to replace the cmd executable itself somehow... I tried that without much success (I either broke the prompt functionality or faced various seemingly security-related roadblocks).

Answer (score 3):

For the Win+X Menu Microsoft decided to use a completely new approach. You won't find anything in the registry (besides the one key that modifies the cmd to powershell...), but it's still customizable.

Basically the links are stored in `%LocalAppData%Microsoft\Windows\WinX` but for some reason they are not normal links, so modification is not completly trivial. Only links that have a hash added to them are recognized here. There is [a tool](https://github.com/riverar/hashlnk) that modifies any lnk file so that it is recognized in this folder (A step by step guide on how to use it can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/113187/how-to-add-items-to-the-new-winx-menu-in-windows-8/).)

Alternatively there is also a tool that allows direct modification of the Win+X menu [found here](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.21). It's probably based on the same idea. They were both developed for Windows 8, but should work in Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, Microsoft dislikes the idea to use their **internal** global hotkey to start some **third-third-party** shell. So, there may be only workarounds.

Try [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I believe, you may bind any hotkey to start your shell.

Write hooking application, which inject your code in the explorer.exe process and run bash.exe instead of cmd.exe. Rudely and a lot of coding...

Create shortcut on the desktop. Set desired hotkey. You can't use Win+X there.

And give a try to [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560). You may use it in "Quake mode" or huge it automatically to the taskbar status area. Also it may [substitute Windows' default terminal](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html).

Comment: While reading the answer, it occured to me one might maybe replace cmd itself with something else "in disguise" ? I'll amend OP (I didn't think it when I wrote the question)

Comment: Placing something in System32 instead of cmd.exe? Bad intention I think. Unless you write some application, which would be aware of cmd.exe commands. Because third party software may run cmd.exe for their purposes.